# How to prevent showing some data from an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a big project for several car companies,developing and taking care of the site.
The problem is that I came on already done site,which btw is written terribly,but aside from that,there are many rules that need to be there in order for the site to work.

The data is stored in DB,and with sql statements I take that data to the site,do stuff with and eventually show it on the screen.
Mostly,i just convert the mysql resultset to an array and through foreach loop i show them in the table.
And here comes the problem,
every row has its status, and the data is shown by its status (example:if `status` is `20`, it's not shown on the screen, but if the `status` is `1` then that row is shown) except one status. It has 2 terms that need to be fullfilled in order for him to show. If the `status=8` and `DATE_ADD(column1,INTERVAL + 30 day)>CURDATE()` it is shown. But that doesn't work. The row with status 8 is always shown.
How do i prevent him from not showing at all .I have PHP if loop in my script that says

```
if($value[11]==8 and $value[21]>$value[22] ){ 
    $value[11]=50//not shown;
}
```

but that also doesn't work. (`$value[11]=status` $`value[21]=DATE_ADD part` and `$value[22]=CURDATE()`)

Please help.Thx in advance

```
 SELECT d1.VIN, d1.brand, d1.make_fin, DATE_FORMAT( d1.dat_ser ,'%d.%m.%Y'), 
        d1.Partner, d1.adress , d1.mail, d1.place, d1.Tel,d1.Mob, d1.uniq,
        d1.idm01_statusi_a,d2.statusname , d1.EMail , DATEDIFF(CURDATE() , d1.dat_ser),
        d1.dat_ser, DATEDIFF(table2.OdgovorDtm, CURDATE() ) , d1.ID_p01, d2.colro, d2.font_color,
        d1.ID_p01,CURDATE(), 
        DATE_ADD(table2.OdgovorDtm,INTERVAL + 30 DAY),
        table2.OdgovorDtm
    FROM table1 as d1 INNER JOIN table2 
        ON d1.ID_p01 = table2.ID_p01
    LEFT JOIN  m01_statusi_a as d2 
        ON d1.idm01_statusi_a = d2.idm01_statusi_a  
    WHERE orgidf in(SELECT d3.orgid FROM u1_org d1 INNER JOIN table3 d2 ON 
       ( d1.idu1 = d2.idu1 ) INNER JOIN lo360.u1_org d3 ON 
       ( d2.idu2 = d3.idu1 ) where d1.orgid = 'HR11338') 
       and d1.idm01_statusi_a in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9 )
       and 1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and d1.IDBRAND in
       ( 1, 2, 3 ) and 1=1 ORDER BY d1.dat_ser ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: I don't see `DATE_ADD` in the query.

Comment: Either you posted the wrong query, or you left out part of the `SELECT` clause. Because`status` is `$value[9]` and `CURDATE()` is `$value[18]`. Your life would be much easier if you used an associative array for the row instead of counting columns.

Comment: I've edited the post,the original query is posted now

Comment: Can you format it readably, like I did before? I don't feel like doing it again for you.